# Get the 20 most recent photos from an album (JSON)

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the 20 most recent photos from an album using the following JSON feed: ([link](https://graph.facebook.com/10151316456544622/photos?fields=picture,name,source,created_time&limit=20))

My code currently works, the only issue is they aren't the most recent photos from the album:

```php
<?php
    $pic_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/10151316456544622/photos?fields=picture,name,source,created_time&limit=20"; //change limit to allow more items
    $pictures = json_decode(file_get_contents($pic_url));
    $countpic= sizeof ($pictures->data); // get the number of pics for later use
    for($p=0; $p<$countpic; $p++):
        $thumb_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$pictures->data[$p]->id."/picture";
        $thumb = $pictures->data[$p]->source;
?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $thumb_url; ?>" class="fresco hover" data-fresco-group="facebook" data-fresco-caption="<?php echo $pictures->data[$p]->name; ?>">
            <div><div class="hover"></div><img style="width: 225px; height:250px;" title="<?php echo $pictures->data[$p]->name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $pictures->data[$p]->name; ?>" src="<?php echo $thumb_url; ?>"></div>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: you'd have sort the resulting array by date taken, then pick off the top (bottom?) 20 from that. if the json returns the pictures in any order, you can't just dump out the first 20 and hope things work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting result from Graph API you may consider to use FQL which is more apt for a situation like the one you are having. You can query the `photos` FQL ([documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo)) within an `album` similar to the Graph API and can also order the same in decreasing by `created` time, so that you will get the most recent one. The query will be like

```
select src,created,caption from photo where album_object_id=10151316456544622 
order by created desc limit 20
```

Which you can view through this [link](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20src,created,caption%20from%20photo%20where%20album_object_id=10151316456544622%20order%20by%20created%20desc%20limit%2020).

Additionally, I would like you to access the Facebook's resources through some Access Token, just to ward of any errors at a later stage. You may use App Access token, as this looks to be publicly available data.

Comment: Unfortunately, FQL is being deprecated after 2.0.  I'm also looking for a recent photos solution using the graph api.